# Make column from pandas dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe where I would like to turn the data in the (first level of the) index into a column. Practically my df looks like this:

```
         col1
CoI     
 AK   0     1
      1    31
      2   NaN 
 BB   0     5
      1    31
      2   NaN
```

And I would like to turn it into this:

```
      col1  CoI

   0     1   AK
   1    31   AK
   2   NaN   AK
   0     5   BB
   1    31   BB
   2   NaN   BB
```

How can I best do this? I think this is a rather basic functionality, but as with many other "basic" pandas things I cannot find info on this anywhere.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)` should do it.  See the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Comment: This link is a little more useful: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index